# how to find only words after equal character with regex?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

For example, in this text:

```
source=sourses/date=2018-02-05
date=2018-02-05/source=swbsource
flight_source=soursewft/date=2018-02-05
date=2018-02-05/source=sources
source=sourseswqa/date=2018-02-05
date=2018-02-05/flight_source=sourcepdt
```

I want to match the only words after equal. I mean the only **sourseswqa**, **swbsource**, **sources**, **sourcepdt**, **sourses**, **soursewft** words.
but it could not be only 'source' or 'flight_source'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's break it down: According to your description, you are interested in the first word following an equals character when the equals character follows the word "source" or "flight_source". The captured word is then terminated by a whitespace character, a forward slash or the end of the string.

A regex similar to this should do the trick:

`(?:flight_source|source)=([^\/\s]+)`

The first group is a non capturing group that matches either "source" or "flight_source". We then look for an equals sign.  After finding an equals sign we start a capturing group where we capture one or more characters that are NOT a forward slash or a whitespace character.

Comment: Your regex is right but i need to get only words, without flight_source or source
I mean only sourseswqa not a source=sourseswqa

Comment: Yes, and you should have that within your captures

Comment: I'm trying it now but get source=sourseswqa

Comment: Thats because you need to extract the captured group from the regex match. You can read more about capture groups on https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups